# --data-urlencode curl to Node.js request or express module

Tags: node.js, curl

I am trying to transform this curl command

```
curl '<url>' -X POST \
  --data-urlencode 'To=<phone>' \
  --data-urlencode 'From=<phone>' \
  --data-urlencode 'Body=<message>' \
  -u '<user>:<pass>'
```

into this Node.js code

```
var request = require('request');

var options = {
    url: 'url',
    method: 'POST',
    auth: {
        'user': 'user',
        'pass': 'pass'
    }
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body);
    }
}

request(options, callback);
```

I don't get how I can add the `--data-urlencode` option in the Node.js version of this code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [curl documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) :

> --data-urlencode
>
> (HTTP) This posts data, similar to the other -d, --data options with
>   the exception that this performs URL-encoding.

So you would use [`form`](https://github.com/request/request#forms) option to send form URL encoded like this :

```
var options = {
    url: 'url',
    method: 'POST',
    auth: {
        'user': 'user',
        'pass': 'pass'
    },
    form: {
        To: 'phone',
        From: 'phone',
        Body: 'message'
    },
    headers: {
        'Accept': '*/*'
    }
};
```

Note that you can use [`request-debug`](https://github.com/request/request-debug) to show the actual request where you could check that body is :

```
To=phone&From=phone&Body=message
```

And to show the actual data sent by curl use as stated [here](https://superuser.com/questions/291424/how-do-you-display-post-data-with-curl), use `--trace-ascii /dev/stdout` :

```
curl '<url>' -X POST --data-urlencode "Body=<message>" -u <user>:<pass>  --trace-ascii /dev/stdout
```